# How to deal with a situation where my colleague thinks being simple is more important than being correctly organized in my documentation

Tags: software-industry, communication, work-environment, work-life-balance

I have a common shared task with my colleague where we need to get some work done by another team that has jumped in to help us with some dead lines coming up, since the 2 of us don't have the bandwidth. He wants to keep things simple so that the new team can understand things very easily. However according to me i think that the new team must have all the details in the right way from the right source with help of a detailed document that has everything they need. We are having conflicting opinions and i think my way should be approached. I think that even if the new team takes some time to understand and refer to the document it will be a 1 stop shop for them to have all the knowledge they need. But i am questioning myself if this is the best option as the team has barely a week to help us with this task. What approach should i take. please advice

Comment: i think it needs to be clarified about the position of you and the colleague, i.e. is your colleague your senior or higher position than you?? who is "calling the shots" here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we've decided that these types of questions are not a good fit for this site: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2134/437

Comment: You're not sure they'll read or rely on these documents, so be care how much time you put into it. Remember, they brought these people in because you don't have a lot of it.

Comment: @Brandin - We both are at the same designation / role in the team.

Answer (score 5):

There are very very few circumstances in which you could actually provide ALL of the information new additions to the team could possibly need.

**Your friend is right.**  Stick to the basics and be available to answer any and all questions as they come up.

BTW, I hope your either not serious about this additional group only being available for a single week.. if you are then I hope this is a minor project.  Adding team members to a complicated project and expecting them to be productive over a total of 40 hours simply isn't realistic.

In either case, a lot of documentation is a complete waste of time.  You should be able to transfer everything they need to know verbally - and by whiteboard - within an hour while supplementing on demand over the 5 days.  If that doesn't give them enough info then the task is simply impossible to perform.

Spending a lot of time documenting whatever it is you think they might want to know won't be a productive use of your time at this point.  If this team is truly going to try and help you then they won't be wasting their time reading whatever it is you put together: they are going to ask.

Comment: Amen Chris simplicity is vastly underrated you can spend weeks doing a complex and fiddly "correct" solution that other people will have difficulty understanding.